# How to match two strings before a specific string

Tags: java, regex

I want to match just two strings before a matched string

```
e.g  Rohan pillai J.
```

Currently i am using :

```
pattern= (?=\w+ J[.])\w+
```

> Answer - pillai
>
> desired answer - Rohan pillai

Comment: I will suggest to use this pattern= \w*\s\w*(?) 
hope it will work. I have checked on live regex site... try it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to take the first two names:

```
\w*\s\w*(?=\sJ\.)
```

---

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/iB1tP3/2)

Explaining:

```
\w*\s         # the first word (name) followed by space
\w*           # the second word (name)
(?=\sJ\.)     # must end with space and "J." - without taking it
```

---

Tip: Generally to escape regex metacharacters (like dot `.`) we use back-slash. Use character class like `[.]` if you want to put emphasis on that character (if you want to make it more visible when you will read this regex).

Comment: @Pshemo. Just to not misleading concepts later, although that isn't a rule.

Comment: I edited your answer a little to change "Avoid using `[.]`" which can be interpreted as "we should not use `[.]` at all costs - `[.]` is almost never valid" into something more neutral. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: @Pshemo. This looks better. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the look ahead in trailing :

```
(\w+) (\w+)(?= J\.)
```

See demo https://regex101.com/r/wH0oU8/1

Or more general you can use `\s` to match any whitespace instead of space :

```
(\w+)\s(\w+)(?=\sJ\.)
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using regex101.com for Java - it doesn't support the full Java flavor of regex. Better use [regexplanet](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html).

Comment: @RealSkeptic Yeah,you are right, but this was a simple regex. anyway thanks for suggestion!